# Comparing variable value with result of a query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I'm trying to pull all the "totalsDate" values from a table "totals" and then either INSERT a new record or UPDATE an existing one based on a variable $date.

```
//getting all the dates from the totals table and assigning to row
    $sqlDate = "SELECT totalsDate FROM totals";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sqlDate);
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $rowDate = $row['totalsDate'];

       //if statement to either update the totals table or create a new record
      if($rowDate = $date){

      $sqlThree = "UPDATE totals SET lodgements = '$lodgementsAfter' WHERE branch_name = '$branchTest' AND totalsDate = '$date'";
      $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sqlThree);

      }

      else {
      $sqlFour = "INSERT INTO totals VALUES(NULL, '$branchTest', 0, '$amount', 0,  '$date')";
      $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sqlFour);
    }



    }
```

The update part works, however my else statement will never be executed and a new record cannot be entered. I also get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

I'm a bit confused on using the mysqli_fetch_array and how to actually use the data?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to google what the given error means?

Comment: okay. And? Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your db query is not correct.  You are not getting a good result back from your query.  The error is saying it expects the result to be an array and its not.  its returning a true of false.

read this [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

for more help.

do you have access to the db command line?  what does the query return.  Are you certain your db connection info is correct?

i found it.

```
 $rowDate = $date   should be $rowDate == $date or $rowDate === $date
```

your sql result is an array

```
$row[0] = "1st result"
$row[1] = "2nd result"
 ..etc
```

so theortically if you have more then 1 result, it should be doing multiple updates/inserts.  are you seeing that?  if its just one result then clearly 2014-02-13, 2014-02-26 are not the same.

```
 $sqlDate = "SELECT totalsDate FROM totals where totalsDate='" . $date . "'";
```

this will return results, with only records that have $date.

```
 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rowcount) < 1))
{
   insert;
}
else
{
   update;
}
```

Comment: Yes everything is correct and as i said, my UPDATE part of the if statement executes 100% correct and works. it's just the else part of the statement that never executes

Comment: what is $date?  i see $rowDate being defined,  i dont see where $date is.

Comment: $date is just a variable which is set from the user input from a textbox. (date format)

That fixes the problem of inserting a new record if the date doesnt exist however, it now doesnt update that, just inserts new one each time lol

Comment: what do you get if you print_r($row);

Comment: i get 
Array ( [totalsDate] => 2014-02-13 )

this is the first record in table

Comment: ok, so you have added the double equals and you are only getting the else condition?   as a test before the if statement, do this.   echo $rowDate . "," . $date;   are they the same?

Comment: I'm getting 2014-02-13, 2014-02-26

13th being the first record in my table and 26th being $date (user input)

Comment: ok.  let me edit answer.

Comment: Yes i understand that - how can i then compare my $date with all array elements in $row then? Just a for loop? and an if $row[i] == $date ~~~ ?

Comment: you are doing a loop already with the while statement.  in your answer you gave me, you said [totalsDate] => 2014-02-13.  1 result, and is not equal to 2014-02-26.

Comment: so now im a bit confused,  does your result have multiple entries like my $row example, or is it 1 result?

Comment: I know that, sorry. but in my table there are multiple dates, e.g. 2014-02-13, 2014-02-17, 2014-02-26 ... how can i move the array to next and then test the next element? for example, the 26th is the 3rd date in the table, if my $date is 2014-02-26, i'm wanting to check it against those e.g. 3 dates? and not just the first one

Comment: so in this example you will end up with 3 modifications to your db table.  2 updates, and 1 insert.  are you seeing that?  throw in an echo $sqlThree and $sqlFour right before their respective query calls to db.  do you see 3 entries?

Comment: Yes i understand what it's doing now! :o

How can i then alter my code to do what i want it do?

Basically take $date, compare against all dates currently in the totals table, field totalsDate.

"IF date exists
then update 

ELSE
INSERT new

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this worked a treat!! I added an extra bit of syntax to the $sqlDate query as there are more than one "branch"

$sqlDate = "SELECT totalsDate FROM totals WHERE totalsDate = '$date' AND branch_name = '$branchTest'";

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One of the problem is that `$query` gets overwritten inside the loop; see here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    // ...
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sqlThree);
    // ...
}
```

You should either a) don't store the result of `mysqli_query()` at all, or b) choose a different variable name, e.g. `$update_res = mysqli_query(...);`.

Better yet, use a single query to do both:

```
INSERT INTO totals VALUES (NULL, :branch, 0, :amount, 0, :date) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lodgements = :lodgements
```

Just make sure the proper unique constraints are defined on the table.